# php executes first with form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>

Tags: php, html, action, forum

php executes first with form action="
it doesn't wait 'form action=' from html...
what's wrong?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo "User Has submitted the form and entered this name : <b> $name </b>";
    echo "<br>You can use the following form again to enter a new name.";
}
?>
```

from my .htaccess. maybe it's braking the code

```
## Turn on and setup apache rewrite ##
RewriteEngine On
Options +Followsymlinks
RewriteBase /

## Dissable directory indexing ##
Options -Indexes

## Remove trailing slash from end of uri ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect to non.php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /([^/]+/)*[^.]+\.php(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php$  $1 [R=301,L]

## Rewrite Rules ##
RewriteRule ^([0-9-a-z-A-Z-_]+)/?$ goto.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^account/(.*)$  $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense, your code seems fine as we see it, so please reedit your question thank you...

Comment: it doesn't wait for the content to be submitted, when i open the page i already see the echo

Comment: @user1047737: I think the problem in your apache server, because your code work fine with me

Comment: the page with the code included on other page, maybe that's what brokes it? [code]// Check if the url is from the owner
$match = array($url_idl);
if (in_array($id, $match))
  {
        include('editthisshit.tpl');
  }
}
[/code]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php

`<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">` and `<form action="" method="post">` are equals because `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` return the script name in execution and `action=""` submit to the page in execution too.

Comment: how can i exclude the php code after successful submit?

Comment: I don't understand, why you need exclude php code?

Comment: i want to run the php code after i submit the content...

Comment: The code in "if(isset($_POST['submit']))" is executed after you submit the form. I can't understand your question yet...

Comment: in my case it's executed before!

Comment: You need that the "echo nl2br($makealink);" execute after html is loaded? Or you need that the "if" is executed after form?

Comment: I need "echo nl2br($makealink);" executed with the html loaded, and php code after i submit. you don't undestand me... the code is working ok if i run it directly, but if the code included to other php file it doesn't. that's how i include the code / Check if the url is from the owner $match = array($url_idl); if (in_array($id, $match)) { include('editthisshit.tpl'); } }

Answer (score 0):

The proper method to check for a POST is to do

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
   ... a POST has occurred ...
}
```

checking for a particular field name is unreliable - you might change the field name and forget to update the if(), the field might get otherwise excluded, etc... The above code is 100% reliable as it doesn't depend on anything in the form itself, EXCEPT for the submission method.

Comment: still it doesn't work if i include this code to other php file, it's simply redirecting to main page after i click on submit.

Comment: Does you code have any redirects in it? Use something like HTTPFox or Firebugs Net tab to view the actual requests/responses between your browser and the server. the form may very well be working properly and you've got something elsewhere in your code causing the redirect.

Comment: yes i have this code in the php if($num == 0){ redirect($url->url_base); exit; }else
but if i remove it, it's stil redirecting but to the php file

Comment: Are you using mod_rewrite? it could be intercepting the post, rewriting, and turning it into a redirect.

Comment: i this that's the case take a look ## Turn on and setup apache

Comment: gah... don't put code blobs into comments. they're impossible to read. put it as an edit to your original question.

Comment: sorry. i'm new here... take a look